# How to properly cache Gatsby page-data.json files on nginx?

Tags: nginx, gatsby

According this [doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/caching/#page-data) we need to remove page-data.json from being cached.

Here's my location directive on nginx

```
    location /page-data {
      add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
    }
```

For some reason the header response is still `max-age=3660000`

How would I go about making sure that all the `page-data.json` from the path `/page-data/` isn't cached.

Comment: According to the doc you linked above, not only the file `page-data.json` but all the JSON files in the `public/page-data/` directory should never be cached by the browser. Please modify your post by adding the actual Nginx configuration to diagnose more, because some other location block may take precedence over handling the path `/page-data/`.

Comment: You're right! One of my locations is blocking all of the json from not being cached